# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException My data length is 23 but error in length & index = 10

Tags: java, android

Iam using `SimpleAdapter` to handle `HashMap` data. My data length is 23 but i get Fatal Exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10`

The error that I am getting

```
E/DetailTimbanganActivity: data length: 23
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ala_application, PID: 7377
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:199)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:136)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:124)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:420)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1412)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:452)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

i've been looking the solution entire this forum but i don't find the answer yet.

Please help and thank you

Comment: An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happens when the code tries to reference something beyond the number of elements in the array.  SO if you expect it to be 23 and its failing at 10 you have a bug / unexpected output.  Have you tried debugging to confirm the array is getting filled properly ?

Comment: I have, when i tried debugging at index 6 the debugging process automatically pause

Comment: @MrR is correct. Provide your code for more help

Comment: You need to provide the code where the exception takes place as well as the data. Dump your data structure and prove that there are 23 elements, which I highly doubt. Without your code, you're asking us to take your word that what you say is correct, but it cannot be so. Show your code so that we can show you where your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Ran into same issue when the "from" and "to" arrays are not of the **same length**. SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) See [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter#SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]))

Answer (score 1):

> I am using SimpleAdapter to handle HashMap data. My data length is 23 but i get Fatal Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

The JVM is not lying to you.  I suspect that the data-length is not the array that the JVM is complaining about.  Looking at the exception it says:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:199)
    ...
```

In looking for the [SimpleAdapter code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java) this might be helpful.  The last line is 199.

```
    final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
    final String[] from = mFrom;
    final int[] to = mTo;
    final int count = to.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
                                            ^^^^^^^
```

That seems to be array that it is talking about.  I'm not 100% sure what is going on but it looks like maybe you are misusing some part of the Android API.  You might consider using a debugger to track this down or otherwise do an audit of the code that is making the call into the widget SimpleAdapter code.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you first have to declare the Array and then Initialise that Array. If you have declared a Reference typed array it is very important to initialise that type array before using it.

If you have declared any reference type array of size 20 and only 10 indices of that array has been initialised then you will get strange kind of errors.

As I am not having a look of the code, so I am guessing this is the problem. It would be great if you could also post the code chunk which is giving you this error. Looking at the code will make the problem more clear.